# KineticJS perimeter collision detection for shapes

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I have two shapes, both circles, and they are moving on the stage. They are just bouncing off the boundaries of the stage when they reach it. What they never do is collide, which is something I would like to add some logic for. As close as I have gotten is

```
shape1.intersects(shape2.getPosition());
```

but that doesn't really come close to what I want to achieve, which would be perimeter collision detection, not just if one point is in another shape.

Comment: you might want to use box2d library along with KineticJS.

Comment: thanks for the info, is there somewhere that I could see an example of box2d and kineticjs together in play?

Comment: I was developing a game using it, but unfortunately the studio has put it on back burner so cannot share the url... and I'm yet to complete the final part of my blog which will integrate the two things together, which I think I'll be able to put through only after Jan23rd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simple bounding box collision detection:

```
function doObjectsCollide(a, b) { // a and b are your objects
   return !(
    ((a.getY() + a.getHeight()) < (b.getY())) ||
    (a.getY() > (b.y + b.getHeight())) ||
    ((a.getX() + a.getWidth()) < b.getX()) ||
    (a.getX() > (b.getX() + b.getWidth()))
   );
}
```